# Salesforce Trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to create a trigger to check if an account exist in another object prior to submission .
The newmember object stores new member request but it has verify if there is an account once the newmember request is submitted for approval.

```
trigger VerifyAcc on Account (after update) {

Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'newmember'].Id;

    if (recordTypeID =='newmember'){

MAP<Id,List<NewMember__c>>Mapnewmemberstoaccounts new MAP<Id,List<NewMember__c>>();
    for(NewMember__c objNewMember:[select Id,name from NewMember__c where
                           Name IN:Trigger.newmap.keyset()])


    {
        if(Mapnewmemberstoaccounts.containsKey(objNewMember.Name)!= null) 
        {

        CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
        e.setMessage('There is no account for this member.');
        throw e;



        }

    }        
    } else{
       CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
        e.setMessage('Couldnt Find anything.');
        throw e;


    } 
}
```

Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your specific question? This logic is very hard to follow and definitely won't work, but it's not at all clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi @DavidReed , trying to check if the record exist in another object. In the event that it does not exist I would like to throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trigger VerifyAcc on Account (after update) {

Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'newmember'].Id;

    if (recordTypeID =='newmember'){
```

A record type Id will never be equal to the text "newmember". You probably mean to be iterating over `Trigger.new` and checking for records whose Record Type Id matches this one.

```
MAP<Id,List<NewMember__c>>Mapnewmemberstoaccounts new MAP<Id,List<NewMember__c>>();
    for(NewMember__c objNewMember:[select Id,name from NewMember__c where
                           Name IN:Trigger.newmap.keyset()])
```

`Trigger.newMap.keySet()` is a `Set<Id>`. Unless the Name field of the `NewMember__c` object contains an Account Id, this query will return no data.

```
    {
        if(Mapnewmemberstoaccounts.containsKey(objNewMember.Name)!= null)
```

You never populate the variable `Mapnewmemberstoaccounts`, so checking it here will not achieve anything. The method `containsKey()` returns a Boolean. It will never return a `null` value.

```
        {

        CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
        e.setMessage('There is no account for this member.');
        throw e;
```

Your code should not throw a `CalloutException` for an error that has nothing to do with a callout. If you wish to stop a specific record from being committed to the database, use the `addError()` method on that record alone. Throwing an exception will result in rolling back the entire transaction.

```
        }

    }        
    } else{
       CalloutException e = new CalloutException();
        e.setMessage('Couldnt Find anything.');
        throw e;
```

Both arms of this `if` statement are coded to throw an exception. That does not make sense; the result will be that (if the enclosing `for` loop ever executes) you cannot insert any Accounts because your trigger always throws an exception.

In rough outline, your trigger should follow a logical path like this:

```
Create a collection variable
for each Account in the trigger set:
    if the Account's record type is "New Member":
        Add the Account's identifier to the set.

Query New Member records matching the Account identifiers.
Build a Map between Identifiers and New Member records.

for each Account in the trigger set:
    if the Account's record type is "New Member":
        Check if the Account's Identifier is in the New Member collection
        If it is, call addError() for this Account
```